# Why isn't my TypeKit font showing?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-4, typekit

The font I am using from TypeKit is called "museo". And it doesn't seem to be loading or displaying on my live-website.

I've added these two lines to my application.html.erb

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/ayn8han.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

And my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "museo",'ProximaNovaRegular',serif;
  src: url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.eot') %>");
  src: url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.eot') %>") format('embedded-opentype'),
  url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.woff') %>") format('woff'),
  url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf') %>") format('truetype'),
  url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.svg#ProximaNovaRegular') %>") format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "museo",'ProximaNovaBold', serif;
  src: url('<%= font_path('proximanova-bold-webfont.eot') %>');
  src: url('<%= font_path('proximanova-bold-webfont.eo') %>t') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('<%= font_path('proximanova-bold-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'),
  url('<%= font_path('proximanova-bold-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'),
  url('<%= font_path('proximanova-bold-webfont.svg#ProximaNovaBold') %>') format('svg');
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be the most basic of answers, but have you checked your "Kit Settings" and made sure your domain is spelled correctly?